# Backbone -managing app views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Basically what I'm trying to do, is to find the best way to manage all my views.So all my views get closed and created when it's necessary.. And because of that, I have created a separate manager inside my `Backbone.Router`instance which takes care of all my views as follows.

**router.js**

```
    AppRouter.prototype.initialize = function () {
             .......
            var eMgr = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events); 
            var vMgr = new ViewManager(); 

            vMgr.add(new vTopMenu({eMgr: eMgr}));
            vMgr.add(new vTooltip({eMgr: eMgr}));

            app_router.on('route:MainMenu', function () {
                vMgr.close_all_views(function(){
                    vMgr.add(new vmainMenu({eMgr: eMgr}));
                    vMgr.render_all_views();
                });
            });

            app_router.on('route:showMap', function () {
                vMgr.close_all_views(function(){
                    vMgr.add(new vMapMenu());
                    vMgr.render_all_views();
                });
            });
...
}
```

As you can see the **TopMenu** and **Tooltip** views are created only once as I don't expect there will be any need to changes their content. And I'd also like to avoid the blank spaces while the views are being loaded...

I'm not sure if this is a good idea though, as all the other views are being closed and re-initiated once I navigate from one route to another.

So the question is, is it a good practice to have these views set up like this? Or should I always re-create the views when any route is triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Some views can be cached if needed. Caching benefits depend on which content are you showing in a view. You have to take into consideration several aspects when making a decision to put a view in the cache:

- Large cache size can impact performance, so chose only ones that are used often for caching.
- Caching is important for those views, which downloading extra resources.
- Be aware, unused views can eat memory resources.

Also, for both cached and uncached cases, you have to remember:

- It also can take significant time to re-render view. Those views which are difficult to render can be just hidden, not removed.
- [Zombie views](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/). Old view should be safely closed, with events unbinding, etc.